# Response.write results in CS0116: A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: asp.net

System.Web.HttpContext.CurrentContext.Response.Write result in this error, when used in an aspx.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to ASP.NET at all. You've written `Response.Write` directly inside a namespace. Simply move it inside a method, or a parameter, but not directly inside a class.

Comment: CS0117: 'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentContext' Response.Write does not work either... Shows an error about the write part.

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Current` only.

Comment: CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'write' and no extension method 'write' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line 40: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.write("hello world");

Comment: C# is case sensitive. Thus `write` should be replaced with `Write`. However, I recommend that you first see some tutorials before using SO on these simple problems ;).

Comment: Oops... Looks like I'm a bit dyslectic.